# CORS Issue with Ionic & Capacitor on android live device

Tags: php, android, ionic-framework, cors, capacitor

Hopefully someone can help me out here; trying to use Ionic with capacitor and running across the following CORS error only on an Android 9 Live Device when attempting to upload an image via POST:

```
E/Capacitor/Console: File: http://localhost/add-item - Line 0 - Msg: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://MYURLGOESHERE/api.php' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

In ionic:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';

...

this.http.post("https:://MYURLGOESHERE/api.php", postObject, {headers: {
     'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
     }
})

...
```

Api PHP Script:

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers: access-control-allow-origin");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *');
header('Access-Control-Max-Age: -1'); 
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST,OPTIONS');
header('Content-Type: application/json'); 

...
```

I've checked that all of the max upload sizes on the server exceed the size of the image I am attempting to upload and I've confirmed that there is no CORS error present using the following CURL test:

```
curl -H "Access-Control-Request-Method: POST" -H "Origin: http://localhost" -I --head https://MYURLGOESHERE/api.php
```

I am just utterly lost as of to what the problem could be.  All other POST requests not uploading the image on the device do not have the same CORS problem.  Anyone have any ideas of what could possibly be going on here or further things I can check on?

Answer (score 0):

To anyone having this same problem the solution was to remove the headers

```
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
```

from the post request and that fixed the problem across all platforms.

Comment: The real problem was that you were using the wrong Content-Type, if you manually added Content-type it should have been 'multipart/form-data'